# Best way to retain information fetch by a Base Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a BaseController and BaseViewModel that all others are derived. It will handle page information that will be used in most pages.

When the user clicks on the side menu the link will be handled with a querystring with the page ID. The page BaseController will use that during OnActionExecuted to fetch the corresponding data and inject it into the model sent to the view.

My issue is how to handle subsequent requests to the same controller (that inherits this BaseController) without having to worry if the pageId is sent or not. For example: When doing a Form and submitting it should still know I am on the same page even though pageId is not sent through the form. The postback should send the same page information previously fetched during the index call with queryString pageId.

It should only change when hitting back on the browser to a previous page or when I specifically specify a different pageID on a queryString.

Edit: I am able also to retrieve the page by the controller name instead of pageId, but I don't know how to get the original called controller name from the BaseController.

Comment: You are making a HTTP request and getting back an HTTP response.  The connection closes after each connection.  Using cookies will help.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Winson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76708868/1671493) pointed me in the right direction.

In the end, this was my solution. To trust the Controller called as I should not have different pages to the same Controller.

```
public override async void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

    var model = ((Controller)filterContext.Controller)?.ViewData.Model as BaseViewModel;

    if (model is null)
    {
        return;
    }
    var controllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]?.ToString();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controllerName))
    {
        return;
    }
    controllerName += "Controller";
    await AddPageDataToModel(model, controllerName);

}
```

That being said, the way to go if you have different pages for the same Controller, you should follow the session strategy like described in Winson's answer.

Comment: What do you mean by *"To trust the Controller called"* (seems incomprehensible)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen,
My pages are stored on the database with a column reference to the controller which it should load it. example of Pages table entry : "PageSales" has "SalesController" in column ControllerName. Each page will have its own controller like a 1-1. This is my special case. This helps me create the links to the page also.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't target the current page just based on the HTTP request. HTTP is a stateless protocol. Even though multiple requests can be sent over the same HTTP connection, the server does not attach any special meaning to their arriving over the same socket.

If you want to track the user's progress from page to page, solutions for these cases include:

- the use of HTTP cookies
- server-side sessions
- hidden variables (when the current page contains a form)
- URL-rewriting using URI-encoded parameters